# Find the random variable given its moments.

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, characteristic-functions

What is the random variable whose nth moment is $ \frac{c}{c+n}$ where $c$is positive.

Comment: Related question, but no good answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/402092/recovering-random-variable-from-its-moments

Answer (score 4):

Assume that $X$ is a random variable with a PDF supported on $\mathbb{R}^+$ and given by $f(x)$.
Assuming, for some constant $c>0$, 
$$ \mathbb{E}[X^n]=\int_{0}^{+\infty}x^n f(x)\,dx = \frac{c}{c+n} $$
we have
$$ (\mathcal{L} f)(s)=\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-sx}f(x)\,dx=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{c}{n+c}\cdot\frac{s^n(-1)^n}{n!}=\frac{\Gamma(c+1)-c\,\Gamma(c,s)}{s^c} $$
and by applying the inverse Laplace transform to both sides we get
$$ f(x) = c x^{c-1}\mathbb{1}_{(0,1)}(x) $$
which we could have guessed by inspection.

Comment: A clever kill - well done!